# SharePoint 2013 Permissions for multiple site collectins

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection

Is it possible to set up permissions groups to have permissions in multiple Site Collections?  If so, how is this managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with SharePoint groups. You can do this with Active Directory Security Groups. You would add users to the AD Sec Group then add the AD Sec Group to one or more site collections within SharePoint groups.

Comment: Thank you very much